# Connection parameters for imposm fail because of special characters

Tags: connection, postgis, openstreetmap, imposm

I want to run imposm to import OSM data to a PostGIS DB.
My problem is that the password for the DB contains special characters like ":" (a colon). I cannot change the password.

The documentation states to use the connection parameter like this:

> The -connection option takes a URL in the format
> postgis://username:password@host:port/databasename or a list of
> parameters like postgis: host=/tmp dbname=osm

However, this produces an error because of the special characters in the password.

```
 parsing database connection URL: parse "postgres://user:pss?wo:r?d!@host/osm": invalid port ":r?d" after host
```

The documentation also says to use a list of parameters but it is not clear to me how these parameters have to be named.

Does anyone know how to pass the connection parameters with a list instead of the URL encryption? I can only find `host` and `dbname` and I dont't know how to write the connection excatly. Or is there a possibility to escape special characters in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must [encode](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) the special characters.

If your password is `pss?wo:r?d!`, the connection URL would be

```
postgresql://user:pss%3Fwo%3Ar%3Fd%21@host/osm
```